# How to know the resistance of the typical drive circuit on the TCD1103GFG datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I'm currently doing some work with TCD1103GFG. I want to know what's the resistance of the three resistors shown below. If possible, I will interface this linear CCD with an Arduino. [image: typical drive circuit example]

Can someone familiar with this answer my question, please?

Comment: What does it tell you in the data sheet?

Comment: I don't think it said anything about the resistor, here's the full datasheet link: [datasheet link](https://www.mouser.tw/datasheet/2/408/TCD1103GFG_Web_Datasheet_en_20190124-1138276.pdf)

Comment: If it's not in the data sheet are you perhaps hoping that someone from Toshiba who was involved in the design of this chip frequents stack exchange?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ju20hAF6OY 0-100 all Info you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's another version of datasheet which can be found on Digikey ([datasheet here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Toshiba%20PDFs/TCD1103GFG.pdf)). It said that two of the resistors' resistance is 150 Ω, and the other one's is 2.2 kΩ. Thanks for all the people who helped me[image: the circuit]

Comment: Good find! Please accept your own answer so this can be closed.